# Updating view based on API response

Tags: react-native

I'm having an issue with showing information in my `App.js` state object in a child component. Below are the relevant parts. `App.js`, `WeatherDetail` is the aforementioned component, and then the response from API request.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import openweather from "../api/openweather";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import WeatherDetail from "./WeatherDetail";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { weather: [], daily: [] };

  onSearchSubmit = async zip => {
    const currentWeather = openweather.get("/data/2.5/weather", {
      params: { zip }
    });

    const fiveDayForecast = openweather.get("/data/2.5/forecast", {
      params: { zip }
    });

    const [weather, daily] = await Promise.all([
      currentWeather,
      fiveDayForecast
    ]);

    this.setState({ weather: weather.data, daily: daily.data.list });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
        <WeatherDetail weather={this.state.weather} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

WeatherDetail.js

```
const WeatherDetail = ({ weather }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Today</h1>
      <h3>City: {weather.name}</h3>
      <h5>Temperature:</h5>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
>forecast:
   base: "stations"
  >clouds: {all: 75}
   cod: 200
  >coord: {lon: -82.54, lat: 40.7}
   dt: 1553023267
   id: 420031370
  >main:
     humidity: 45
     pressure: 1030
     temp: 44.22
     temp_max: 46.99
     temp_min: 41
   name: "Elyria"
```

Now, `weather.name` shows up in the view with no problem. If I try to grab any information deeper than that I get an error saying the property is undefined. For example, `weather.main.temp` is how I thought I would get the temperature but it shows that error. `weather.main` alone gives an obvious error, but it shows the object I'm trying to access in the message. So I'm confused about how that can be when `weather.main.temp` also says the property (main) is undefined. Am I trying to access the object incorrectly or is something else set up wrong?

Comment: Can you show your state and the rest of `App.js`?

Comment: have you tried to make an api request using postman ... to see exactly how the res obj is structured

Comment: Here is the whole App.js. I have another key in state because I want to try and do a 5 day forecast also, but at this point it's more of a placeholder.

https://gist.github.com/cdekk3r/0c1e829e7003e07bd0db8ba5363099ee

Comment: I haven't tried postman.. axios is all I know how to use at this point. I finished an online course a couple of weeks ago so I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: try installing postman (( it's a tool not an npm module like axios )), it's very easy to use and will allow you to make an api request in a very easy way so you can see you res object in an organized way ...

Comment: Can you post the output of a console.log(this.state.weather) before the return statement in the render method?

Comment: @CodySwann - Sorry for delayed response. gist.github.com/cdekk3r/6b094b41dc32bca076c551e7bcc9758a

Comment: Another thing I just noticed is if I try to show `{weather.main.temp}` and then search for a zip, I get an empty array from the `console.log(this.state.temp). That explains why the error says "can't read property temp of undefined". I still don't understand how it's empty when `weather.main` gets the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes with the initial render, before you have received results from the API. The first time `WeatherDetail` renders, it has the default state, which you've set to `state = { weather: [], daily: [] };`. This means that on initial render there is no `main` attribute existing on `state.weather`. It's just an empty array. The attributes only exist when you populate them on running `onSearchSubmit`.

I would add some validation in your `WeatherDetail` component. Something like the below:

```
const WeatherDetail = ({ weather }) => {
  const { name, main } = weather;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Today</h1>
      <h3>City: { name ? name : ''}</h3>
      <h5>Temperature: { main ? main.temp : '' }</h5>
    </div>
  );
};
```

That way on initial render if the attributes don't exist you can still render empty strings, and when the state gets populated and the correct attributes exist, it will render the correct content.

Comment: It's a pleasure!

Comment: Sorry, but I have a follow up question. I have the same issue trying to reach further into that response. 

>forecast
  >weather: Array(1)
     >0:
        description: "scattered clouds"
        icon: "03d"
        id: 802
        main: "Clouds"

I had to change the prop from weather to current since there is already a weather property in the response. I need to access the description and icon. For some reason I can already access name without making it a variable, so `const { name, weather} = current`, but if I do weather[0] I get that same error.

Comment: That didn't format properly so I put it in a repl for clarity. https://repl.it/@cdekk3r/LiveIdenticalAfkgaming. Even if I access weather[0] I'm assuming .description would then give the error.

Comment: You can check that the array has values in it by doing `if (weather && weather.length) { ...`. then set the variable values.

Comment: Got it. I did `if (weather) { const today = weather[0]; const description = today.description; const icon = today.icon;}` They console.log correctly within the if statement, but outside of it I get description/icon is not defined.

Comment: Looks like similar to the temperature issue, `{weather ? weather[0].description : ""}` works. I guess I just don't understand why I can't chain together properties instead of the ternary operator. That's how it was done in one of my course projects with no issue. Maybe I missed something in how I set up my App.js.

Comment: I've set up my 5 day forecast [here](https://gist.github.com/cdekk3r/7c3b659d1462c65cca2cad375ecde9c8). In `DayItem.js` I can use `day.main.temp` without error. How is it that works but `current.main.temp` gives the undefined error?

Comment: The problem is that on initial render you're trying to access nested items that don't exist. Initially the components are rendered with default state. After you submit the data is populated and the components re-rendered. It works for DayItem.js because that's initiated only when there are items in your days in DailyForecast.js, which for default state is empty array. DayItems don't get rendered initially (only when data is populated). Either initialize the default state with nested variables (even if they're empty), or check that items are there before you try and use them.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much!